# Why is $agHg^{-1}a^{-1}=gHg^{-1}$ for $a \in H$ (with $H$ as a subgroup)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I got to read this in Rotman's Introduction to Group Theory:

[image]

I don't understand the part that $agHg^{-1}a^{-1}=gHg^{-1}$ for $a \in H$ (with $H$ as a subgroup) ... any help ?

Here, $N_g(x)$ is the normalizer of $x$

Comment: Should it be "Now $H$ acts on $X$ by conjugation" instead of "Now $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation? Maybe it was the typo that confused you. If "$G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation", then $\{H\}$ cannot be an orbit because $\mathcal O(H)=X$.

Comment: Yes ! if G should be H everything makes sense

Comment: Yeah, probably a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a different scenario. As $\{gHg^{-1}\}$ is an orbit of size 1 with the operation being the conjugation, $agHg^{-1}a^{-1}=H$, or else the orbit wouldn't be of size 1.

Comment: I propose to delete my answer now that the original question has been vandalised (and made, as you so clearly explain, absolutely trivial!)